# How to insert Javascript variables into a database

Tags: javascript, sql

i would like to insert variables into my database, some are php wich works fine, but the problem is the javascript variables, it does not work. im quite new to this any help would be nice.

this is my first question, im sorry if i get the code blocks wrong.

```
echo '<br>
<form><input type="button" id="startbutton" value="start time control" onClick="starttime()" style="width:225px; margin-top:0px; "><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tekst = "";
var startdatum;
var starttijd;
var stopdatum;
var stoptijd;
var startdatumtijd;

function starttime()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

    starttijd = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
    startdatum=(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date);
    startdatumtijd = (startdatum + " " + starttijd);

    startbutton.value = "stop timecontrol";
    startbutton.onclick = timecontrol;
}

function timecontrol()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    tekst = document.getElementById("inputtekst").value;

    stoptijd = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
    stopdatum=(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date); 
    var stopdatumtijd = (stopdatum + " " + stoptijd);


    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO `vtiger_timecontrol` (`title`,`relconcept`, `relatedto`, `date_start`,`time_start`,`date_end`,`time_end`)VALUES ('.$ticketno.' , \'Support_\' , '.$ticketnummer.' , startdatum , starttijd , einddatum , eindtijd );");
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO `vtiger_crmentity` (`description`,`setype`,`createdtime`,`modifiedtime`,`viewedtime`)VALUES(tekst,\'Timecontrol\',stopdatumtijd,stopdatumtijd,stopdatumtijd);");

}</script></form>';
```

What should happen is when i press a button, it saves the time in a variable, the second time i press the button it will save the time in another variable, now i want these time variables to be saved in my database.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `tx`? A php variable? :o

Comment: Ok...in short, what you could do is make an AJAX request from your JavaScript, sending JavaScript variables to another PHP script. From here, you'd be able to store information into the database.

Comment: @SiGanteng ```tx``` is generally the identifier used for examples of the JS API for SQLlite/LocalStorage. I'm guessing there's some copy and pasting going on without quite understanding what's going on.

Comment: @Wim - I think you need to look at the differences between server-side and client-side; and then perhaps look at mechanisms like AJAX for bridging the differences. In brief, from Javascript you can generally only access resources in the client's browser - to store anything on the server you need to keep the data flowing through the server side language. If you've looked at the SQLlite Javascript implementations, they store their data on the *client* - hence why it wont be working as expected!

Comment: @FergusMorrow thats clears up a lot, thank you. i will try using AJAX, i never have but i'll see what i can do.

Comment: It's good to experiment and explore a bit, very commendable! A tip, in my opinion, is to view the two languages as building separate applications. You then need to think about exactly what data needs to be shared between them and then look in to AJAX and how that can help. It can be confusing and full of pitfalls at first - but perseverance helps! Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax worked:

```
if (radio2.checked == true)
{
    var checked = 0;        
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("post","tc.php?ticketid='.$ticketnummer.'&ticketnummer='.$ticketno.'&hidden1=" + startdatum+"&hidden2=" + starttijd+"&hidden3=" + stopdatum+"&hidden4=" + stoptijd+"&hidden5=" + tekst+"&hidden6=" + stopdatumtijd + "&hidden7=" + checked, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
else if (radio3.checked == true)
{
    var checked = 1;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("post","tc.php?hidden8='.$current_user.'&ticketid='.$ticketnummer.'&ticketnummer='.$ticketno.'&hidden1=" + startdatum+"&hidden2=" + starttijd+"&hidden3=" + stopdatum+"&hidden4=" + stoptijd+"&hidden5=" + tekst+"&hidden6=" + stopdatumtijd + "&hidden7=" + checked , false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

thank you for the advice.

Comment: Just seen this, that's awesome you managed to go and get it working based on the pointers in the comments above; congrats!